# An error occurs when connecting to mysql in ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Now I am using mysql test server in my company.

An error occurs when connecting to mysql test server in ec2 instance!
This is a result of execution in EC2 instance.
[image]

This is a result of execution in my house!
I didn't config anything for my house ip in firewall of server!
However, it's no prob. So I think server's firewall is ok!

[image]

And It's my security group!
[image]

Now inbound and outbound allow all things.
I will modify it later and I think security group is not prob.
Then, what's a prob????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create the `user1` account in MySQL? If it was something like `CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' ...`, then you will not be able to connect remotely. Instead you will need to do this:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' ...
```

Once created, remember to assign privileges to `'user1'@'%'`, then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to ensure everything is properly set.